# How to make the sum of output to 1

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

My (PyTorch) sum of model’s output isn’t 1. And this is the structure of model.

```
LSTM(4433, 64)
LSTM(64, 64)
Linear(64, 4433)
Sigmoid()
```

And this is the predicted output of the model.
Input

`[1, 0, 0, …, 0, 0]`

Output

```
[.7842, .5, .5, …, .5, .5]
```

Do you know any function that can make its sum 1?

Comment: I assume you are trying to make a classification model and get probability value of each class as output(to make sum of output as 1). Then you should use [softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html#torch.nn.Softmax) instead of sigmoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sigmoid** activation function maps every input to a value between [0, 1], without taking into account other elements in the input vector. However, **Softmax** does a similar transformation but the output vector sums 1.

**TL;DR:** use softmax instead of sigmoid.